# Best backend for social network iOS mobile app

Tags: ios, database

Right now I almost done with my mobile iOS social networking app (written on Swift) and I need to choose backend.

Requirements:

1. Database can be accessed from web - I plan on making limited website interface for this social network too (like Instagram)
2. Login Password + Facebook/Twitter integration (azure and aws are highly complicated about custom login entities,at least way harder than Parse)
3. Scalability - can maintain server with millions of active users (I tried using Parse, but everyone says it's unreliable)
4. Reliability and other typical BaaS features like push notification, file storage etc.
   What would your recommendations be, it seems like there are so many different choices, but each of them has at least 1 disadvantage which turns me down.

Heard about Kinvey, but I am not sure if it matches points **3** and **4**.